# Add JSON objects to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object employees which I would like to populate with the data in my localstorage. I first saved my JSON object to local storage using `stringify()`   .

```
    sessionStorage.setItem('Employee3', JSON.stringify({id: 3, firstName: 'Dwight', lastName: 'Schrute', title: 'Assistant Regional Manager', managerId: 2, managerName: 'Michael Scott', city: 'Scranton, PA', officePhone: '570-444-4444', cellPhone: '570-333-3333', email: 'dwight@dundermifflin.com', reportCount: 0}));
```

Now I want to populate my employees object:

```
employees: {},

populate: function() {
    var i = i;
    Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(key){
        if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
            this.employees[i] = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
            i++;
        }
   });  
},
```

The function `$.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key))` returns the JSON object correctly. Assigning it to the employees object fails:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: `employees` is an object whereas you are treating it as an array. How about declaring `employees` an array?

Comment: In the original snippet they didnt use localstorage, I am adding it now. They treated it as an array and it worked:         this.employees[4] = {id: 4, firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Halpert', title: 'Assistant Regional Manager', managerId: 2, managerName: 'Michael Scott', city: 'Scranton, PA', officePhone: '570-222-2121', cellPhone: '570-999-1212', email: 'jim@dundermifflin.com', reportCount: 1};

Comment: @shahkalpesh: That's incorrect. In JavaScript you can access properties on objects using square brackets. It doesn't necesarily mean an access to an index of an array

Comment: @Kenneth: I am aware. Which property is being accessed here? What does `i` hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.forEach` doesn't preserve `this`, so you'll have to preserve it yourself. Either of these will work (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)):

```
Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(key){
    if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
        this.employees[i] = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        i++;
    }
}, this);

var self = this;
Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(key){
    if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
        self.employees[i] = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        i++;
    }
});
```

Also, consider using the browser's `JSON.parse()` instead of jQuery's. Any browser that supports `Array.forEach` will support `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Or use `.bind(this)` on the iterator function.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, there's no reason to use `JSON.parse` - jQuery tries that, then falls back to another method. I'd rather use that than not be sure

Comment: @MerynStol - That would only work if the OP only ever wanted to use one context for that array because `this` cannot be overridden. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: @Ian - But the OP is using `Array.forEach`, so there's already an assumption about browser support. I personally only like to use framework-specific functions if no reasonable native alternative exists, which is why I made the suggestion.

Comment: @tjameson how do you mean? If you do the bind each time `forEach` is called, you'll get the same effect as your first suggestion. Your suggestion is slightly shorter, easier to type, but not all methods support a second parameter for giving value for this. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @MerynStol - Yes, in this instance, but in a different situation it would not work. For example, if the array were in a global scope and called from different functions with different scope.

Comment: And technically, not **all** browsers that support `forEach` also support `JSON`. Firefox 1.5 supported `forEach`, but not until Firefox 3.5 did it support `JSON`. I know that probably doesn't matter, so I'm just being a pain :) You're right though, and I would do the same - I didn't realize how close in support they both were

Comment: @tjameson I've posted what I meant as a different answer, just to be clear. I think it does almost exactly the same as your first suggestion. However the code is used.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach((function(key){
    if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
        this.employees[i] = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        i++;
    }
}).bind(this));
```

Calling `.bind(this)` on a function will return a new function bound to the value for `this` (in the current scope).

the advantage to this is that you don't need to remember which methods support the second "value for this" parameter. It always works. For example, this also works for when adding event listeners to DOM nodes.

tjameson's first suggestion is probably to be preferred in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the value of `this` inside the `forEach` callback. Also, And you don't need jQuery to parse JSON.

You can do this instead:

```
employees: {},

populate: function() {
    var that = this;
    var i = i;
    Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(key){
        if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
            that.employees[i] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
            i++;
        }
   });  
},
```

Comment: `Also, And you don't need jQuery to parse JSON.` - then why does your answer still have `$.parseJSON`? :)

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer in a hurry and cut out the wrong part.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the scope of `this`. When you are inside the foreach-callback this is not referring to the correct instance.

You need to save a reference to `this` before and then access the object through that reference (self in the following example):

```
function something(){    
    var self = this;
    ** snip **
    employees: {},

    populate: function() {
        var i = i;
        Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(key){
            if (/^Employee/.test(key)) {
                self.employees[i] = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
                i++;
            }
       });  
    },
    ** snip ** 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to parse JSON, two simple functions will do the job (hope that was the idea):

```
var employees = {};

function setEmployee( data ) {
    var id = data.id;
    sessionStorage.setItem('Employee' + id, JSON.stringify( data ));
};

function getEmployee( id ) {
    employees[id] = sessionStorage.getItem('Employee' + id);
};

var oneEmployee = {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Dwight',
    lastName: 'Schrute',
    title: 'Assistant Regional Manager',
    managerId: 2,
    managerName: 'Michael Scott',
    city: 'Scranton, PA',
    officePhone: '570-444-4444',
    cellPhone: '570-333-3333',
    email: 'dwight@dundermifflin.com',
    reportCount: 0
};

setEmployee( oneEmployee );

getEmployee( 3 );
```